# How to concatenate two dataframes with different indices along column axis

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, concatenation

I want to merge 2 dataframes and first is `dm.shape = (21184, 34)`, second is `po.shape = (21184, 6)`. I want to merge them then it will be 40 columns. I write as this

```
dm = dm.merge(po, left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

then it is `dm.shape  = (4554, 40)` my rows decreased.

P.s `po` is the `PolynomialFeatures` of numerical data of `dm`.

Answer (score 2):

Problem is different index values, so convert them to default `RangeIndex` in both DataFrames:

```
df = dm.reset_index(drop=True).merge(po.reset_index(drop=True), 
                                     left_index=True, 
                                     right_index=True)
```

Solution with [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) - by default outer join, but if same index values in both working same:

```
df = pd.concat([dm.reset_index(drop=True), po.reset_index(drop=True)], axis=1)
```

Comment: Why don't you use `ignore_index=True` instead of `reset_index`?

Comment: @MykolaZotko - because `axis=1`

Comment: @MykolaZotko - it convert columns names to rangeindex if use `ignore_index=True` and same problem like before

Answer (score 0):

Or use:

```
dm = pd.DataFrame([dm.values.flatten().tolist(), po.values.flatten().tolist()]).rename(index=dict(zip(range(2),[*po.columns.tolist(), *dm.columns.tolist()]))).T
```

Comment: Solution working only all data are numeric, if not, it convert numeric to strings.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method `join` and set the parameter `on` to the index of the joined dataframe:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1, 2]}, index=[1,2])
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'col2': [3, 4]}, index=[3,4])

df1.join(df2, on=df2.index)
```

Output:

```
   col1  col2
1     1     3
2     2     4
```

The joined dataframe must not contain duplicated indices.